# Ajax Upload: How to make each file I upload have its own extension as a request parameter?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, file-upload

So I am loooking at [Ajax Upload library](http://valums.com/ajax-upload/). I made it work with my server and upload multiple files. But I dont get how to set such parameter as file extension for each difrent file I upload. So I wonder how to do such thing, because alI can do now is set general parameters, not individual.

Comment: Why would you want to add something like file extension as a parameter in the JS? Can you not detect the extension for each file on the server when you are processing it?